# System.Web.HttpcontextBase problems in Orchard 1.8 (possibly due to Visual studio 2015)

Tags: stack-overflow, orchardcms, autofac, httpcontext, orchardcms-1.8

I'm running a website on Orchard 1.8.

I tried Visual Studio 2015 RC and built my Orchard project using this version. Since then, my error logs are flooded with the `Autofac` errors saying that **`System.Web.HttpContextBase`** cannot be resolved (see stacktrace below).

I reverted back to VS2013 (i did **not** uninstall VS2015) but the errors didn't go away. I'm not sure if this is even the problem...

My test environment to which I deployed the solution also started having the same problems.

Could this be related to the .NET version which is installed? (`4.6` local, `4.5.2` remote)

Also, this seems to be causing stack overflow exceptions which are a huge problem at the moment. Any leads are highly appreciated!

```
2015-06-08 13:34:54,921 [25] Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - (null) - An unexpected exception was caught
 (null)
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: A delegate registered to create instances of 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' returned null.
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Delegate\DelegateActivator.cs:line 70
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 61
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ConstructorParameterBinding.cs:line 114
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ReflectionActivator.cs:line 122
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Lifetime\LifetimeScope.cs:line 270
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 64
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource.c__DisplayClass4.b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Features\Collections\CollectionRegistrationSource.cs:line 75
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Delegate\DelegateActivator.cs:line 69
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 61
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Delegate\DelegateActivator.cs:line 69
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 61
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ConstructorParameterBinding.cs:line 114
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ReflectionActivator.cs:line 122
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Lifetime\LifetimeScope.cs:line 270
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 64
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Autofac.Features.Collections.CollectionRegistrationSource.c__DisplayClass4.b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Features\Collections\CollectionRegistrationSource.cs:line 75
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Delegate\DelegateActivator.cs:line 69
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 61
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Activators\Delegate\DelegateActivator.cs:line 69
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 79
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 61
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 123
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 85
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Core\Lifetime\LifetimeScope.cs:line 232
   at Autofac.Features.LazyDependencies.LazyRegistrationSource.c__DisplayClass5`1.c__DisplayClass7.b__4() in c:\Projects\OSS\autofac\Core\Source\Autofac\Features\LazyDependencies\LazyRegistrationSource.cs:line 85
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.New(String contentType) in C:\projects\web\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 95
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Get(Int32 id, VersionOptions options, QueryHints hints) in C:\projects\web\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 219
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentGetExtensions.Get[T](IContentManager manager, Int32 id, VersionOptions options) in C:\projects\web\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\ContentExtensions.cs:line 160
   at Orchard.Settings.CurrentSiteWorkContext.Get[T](String name) in C:\projects\web\src\Orchard\Settings\CurrentSiteWorkContext.cs:line 13
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.FindResolverForState[T](String name) in C:\projects\web\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:line 0
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.GetState[T](String name) in C:\projects\web\src\Orchard\Environment\WorkContextImplementation.cs:line 27
   at Orchard.ContentPermissions.Security.AuthorizationEventHandler.Complete(CheckAccessContext context)
   at Orchard.Events.DelegateHelper.c__DisplayClass14_0`2.b__0(Object target, Object[] p) in C:\projects\web\src\Orchard\Events\DelegateHelper.cs:line 116
   at Orchard.Events.DefaultOrchardEventBus.TryInvokeMethod(IEventHandler eventHandler, Type interfaceType, String messageName, String interfaceName, String methodName, IDictionary`2 arguments, IEnumerable& returnValue) in C:\projects\web\src\Orchard\Events\DefaultOrchardEventBus.cs:line 80
   at Orchard.Events.DefaultOrchardEventBus.TryNotifyHandler(IEventHandler eventHandler, String messageName, String interfaceName, String methodName, IDictionary`2 eventData, IEnumerable& returnValue) in C:\projects\web\src\Orchard\Events\DefaultOrchardEventBus.cs:line 53
```

Comment: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/578782#post1351224 I have the same issue. Cant use the orchard command line on my home PC. I never installed VS2015. I also reinstalled visual studio, .net etc. and that didn't help, but VS is famous for being a complete bastard to totally remove...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fixed in [this](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/commit/ce630f980c7a79ae17b36598f3834c4ffd523739) commit for 1.9, i was able to pick out some of the parts of the commit and was able to fix the error.

Comment: Did you ever find the underlying cause of the issue? For me, this exact same behavior started occurring after recent upgrade to Win10 and install of VS2015. I'm concerned about cherry picking the commit you referenced due to unintended side effects. If you have any additional info I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Strange thing is that the errors mysteriously stopped happening while debugging in VS2013 but continue to happen on precompiled builds I create with VS2013 developer cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error showing up when running the command "feature enable Orchard.Packaging" after a build in Visual Studio 2015.

I went back to VS 2012, made a fresh build of the project and ran again the same command "feature enable Orchard.Packaging", it started working.

Finally I was able to run the command "package create...". Modules and Themes started being updated agan.